# What's the recommended way to add a user-defined iterator tag for new kinds of iterator?

Tags: c++

What's the recommended way to add a user-defined iterator tag for new kinds of iterator? Eg, what do the c++ committee members that have studied this recommend?

Is it fine to derive the new iterator tag from forward_iterator_tag or input_iterator_tag.

I want to make it so users of advance, distance, next, prev, etc for iterators with this new tag will implicitly take advantage of the extra capabilities that models of new iterator kind will have.

Comment: Do you have a concise sample, of what are you trying to do/achieve? Asking for _the best_ way may come up considered of topic, because of being opinionated, or too broad.

Comment: Unfortunately in C++ there are many consequences to how you choose to solve a problem and so "best" is important to include otherwise I might get some poorly considered "worked for me" answers with problems. Anyway The question includes exactly what I'm trying to do - I have new kinds of iterator and iterators are tagged in C++ so optimised implementations of functions can be defined and selected by the c++ type system. These are standard aspects of the standard iterators - so I'm looking for how to make my custom iterators fit in to the c++ concept of iterators.

Answer (score 0):

You should not derive from std::forward_iterator_tag. It is just a typedef in your custom iterator (which actually does not need a base class) to classify the capabilities of your iterator.

See 24.4 Iterator requirements

Comment: How will I make users of advance et. al select an appropriate implementation of those functions without a new tag? ADL is not enough because there will be many iterator types that all model a new kind of iterator and there should only be one implementation of advance et al which works for all those iterators.

Comment: I read the iterator requirements of https://isocpp.org/files/papers/N3690.pdf (I haven't got a copy of a ratified standard version to hand). It doesn't specify what to do with new kinds of iterator that have enhanced capabilities. I wonder if this is one of those things where the answer would only be found at gotw. There will be a number of iterator types with extra capabilities that can be indicated with a new tag. Is that supported in C++? Then can I make users of advance et al use those capabilities implicitly?